# jmeter mvc web app newbie

Tags: jmeter

i'm new to jmeter.

followed the web app load test tutorial. created http defaults, and http request
it gives me that error in the log

```
2014/12/08 15:07:29 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.<clinit>(HTTPHC4Impl.java:235)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerFactory.getImplementation(HTTPSamplerFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:64)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1141)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1130)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:431)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:258)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 8 more

2014/12/08 15:07:29 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: JMeter Users 1-1 
2014/12/08 15:07:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: JMeter Users 1-2 
2014/12/08 15:07:30 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerFactory.getImplementation(HTTPSamplerFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:64)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1141)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1130)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:431)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:258)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2014/12/08 15:07:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: JMeter Users 1-2
```

it is strange that it gives ssl error, i don't want ssl at all
is something missing from my java? i have jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.6.0_41

thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you run JMeter ?

Comment: I work in Win7, and run the jmeter.bat from bin folder

Comment: Can you please share snapshot of your test plan & HTTP Sampler.

Comment: @JmeterPerfTest how to share test plan? normally i created a new web test plan. it creates a default items for jmeter.apache.org, the home page, and another page for the changes. i cannot paste/send the jmx file or the log (they're too long)

Comment: by snapshot i meant screen shot, jpg image
you can first try the answer provided by Dmitri T

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with your Java installation.

1. Reinstall Java (preferably into a folder without spaces in its path, i.e. C:\Java)
2. Same for JMeter. Download latest JMeter bundle and unzip it somewhere, i.e. C:\Jmeter
3. Open Windows Command Prompt
4. Type the following

   ```
   SET JAVA_HOME=c:\java
   SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
   pushd c:\jmeter\bin
   jmeter.bat
   ```

Above commands do the following:

- set environment variable called JAVA_HOME with value of c:\java
- add \bin folder of Java to your system path
- navigate to jmeter folder
- launch jmeter

Further steps are described in [Getting Started: Scripting with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/get-started-scripting-jmeter) guide.

If above solution doesn't help can you post full *jmeter.log* file somewhere so we could take a look, it usually contains enough information to get to the bottom of any issue.